# TFS-GIT configuration with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs, tfs-2015

I have created a GIT project in TFS2015 having Java code in it.
But I am unable to fetch the source code from TFS-GIT.
My Jenkins is set-up in Linux server.
I have provided git.exe path at Manage jenkins -> Configure System.
Using GIT Plugin in Jenkins, while providing the url for TFS-GIT repo it is throwing error Failed to connect.
So I tried using TFS plugin in Jenkins.
I am able to connect to TFS but it fails with an error  nothing to poll.

Please let me know the correct way to configure Jenkins to poll TFS-GIT source code.

Comment: You can also use a tfs cross-platform build agent that runs on linux and will connect to tfs directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GIT Plugin used in Jenkins was of older version. I upgraded the plugin to latest, which gave me option for providing credentials. I provided my credentials used to access TFS and it worked like wonder.

Comment: Please mark your own reply as answer. Furthermore would be nice if you edit the question and the answer so to explicit the versions involved.